# Pyspark Py4JJavaError:

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter

I have tried to run the following simple code in Jupyter notebook using pyspark.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Collinear Points")
sc = SparkContext('local',conf=conf) 
   
from pyspark.rdd import RDD 
numbRDD=sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,-1,-4,-6])
# Create map() transformation to cube numbers
cubedRDD = numbRDD.map(lambda x: x**3)

# Collect the results
numbers_all = cubedRDD.collect()
```

I get the following error. Could you please give any hints that would fix it?

TIA.
Sheri

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
> in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (W504456FT.anybank.de executor driver):
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess
> error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden    at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)    at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:165)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)   at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die
> angegebene Datei nicht finden     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native
> Method)   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)     at
> java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)   ... 16 more

Comment: Can you post the full trace?

Comment: per the translation of "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden" (to "The system can not find the stated file") I think the program is unable to find the pyspark or Java bundle. This means you have not added the paths to your environment variables or the paths are unreachable. For further help, would be helpful if you can share the full trace.